# Bigquery - Merging Arrays With One Common Value

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble finding a way to merge two arrays with common values. What I'm trying to create is an array to be used as an archive of sorts for customer attributes which're aren't needed in the immediate future.

I've whipped up a DB fiddle as an example of the data I'm working with.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gKGsBFSgzZkTv3bMNhU9UG/1

The first two results are the two separate tables, and the three result is what I hope to get by merging those two arrays together.

Only method I can think of is maybe unnesting both tables, joining together and then remaking the array but I'm hoping there's a cleaner/more efficient method as I'm working with a lota data.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
with test as (
    select 'user 1' as user, ['attribute 1', 'attribute 2', 'attribute 3'] as attributes union all
    select 'user 2' as user, ['attribute 1', 'attribute 2', 'attribute 3'] as attributes 
),
test_2 as (
    select 'user 1' as user, ['attribute 4', 'attribute 5', 'attribute 6'] as attributes union all
    select 'user 2' as user, ['attribute 7', 'attribute 8', 'attribute 9'] as attributes 
)

select t.user
    , array_concat(t.attributes,t2.attributes)
from test t
join test_2 t2
 on t.user=t2.user
```

The array_concat function will concatenate the two columns together for each matching user column.
With the sample data the following is produced:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ARRAY_CONCAT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_concat) to meet your requirement since it will merge two arrays and you can provide the condition in the [WHERE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#where_clause) clause.

```
with test as (
   select 'user 1' as user, ['attribute 1', 'attribute 2', 'attribute 3'] as attributes union all

   select 'user 2' as user, ['attribute 1', 'attribute 2', 'attribute 3'] as attributes
),
test_2 as (
   select 'user 1' as user, ['attribute 4', 'attribute 5', 'attribute 6'] as attributes union all

   select 'user 2' as user, ['attribute 7', 'attribute 8', 'attribute 9'] as attributes
)
select t.user,array_concat(t.attributes,t_2.attributes) as attributes
from test as t,test_2 as t_2 
where t.user=t_2.user
```

**Output Table**

[image]